# Apache wildcard subdomain to tail directory

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, subdomain

I'm trying to follow on how to make subdomains that tails a specific directory, so for example I go to `http://sub.mydomain.com` and it should take me the root of `/var/www/sub`. `http://randomdir.mydomain.com` should take me to `/var/www/randomdir`.

I followed a lot of answers here on SF but none has helped at all. Basically what I have done is made a wildcard A record `*.mydomain.com` a couple days ago, now I've added a virtualhost in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain.com.conf` which contains this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cake.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

However, when restarting apache2, I get this returned:

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/%1] does not exist
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx for ServerName
 ... waiting Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/%1] does not exist
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx for ServerName
```

How do I manage to create wildcard subdomains that point to a directory based on the prefix of the domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `DocumentRoot /var/www/%1` directive to `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1`.

Answer (score 1):

This document, [Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html) seems to cover exactly what you are trying to do.

The areas covering the VirtualDocumentRoot directive are covered in more detail on the [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) documentation page and might be of particular interest to you.